# Reading a textfile to authenticate user in PHP with JS and echoing it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So this should be easy enough. Basically we have a URL that is a link to take a user to a help page. With this link, the user needs to be authenticated. When the user clicks the link, it reads the file contents from the PHP and sends them through. I believe you need to echo the PHP in the JS and this is where I am hazy.   It's not a lot of code but can someone take a look and see if it looks correct?  Below is the PHP in the template.  Thanks. I tried testing it but I don't think it's working. Appreciate any help.

```
    <li>
     <a id="help" target="_blank"><?=l(111)?><div style="display:none;" id="help-creds"><? echo file_get_contents('d:/www_resources/htpasswd/app-file.plaintext') ?></div>
      </a>
   </li>

    //Js to echo the PHP
     var helpCreds = $("#help-creds").text();
     var $help = $('#help');
         $(help).attr("href", "https://app.com/help" + helpCreds);
```

Comment: You are ending up with a link like: https:/app.com/help123143123. I guess it should be something like https:/app.com/help?creds=123143123

Comment: `$(help)`? Sounds like `$("#help")` would be more correct (Although I have no idea what you mean by _"js to echo the PHP"_)

Comment: thanks, forgot to mention that was a var declared earlier

Comment: Yes, but it's still `$(help)` and not `$help.attr(...`

Comment: yes, sorry you are right